# Slicing audio given video frames

Tags: python, pytorch, signal-processing, librosa, torchaudio

I have audio from a video that I've loaded with PyTorch. Given a starting index and ending index corresponding to the video segment of interest, along with the video FPS and audio sampling rate, how would I go about extracting the slice of audio that matches the segment of interest of the video?

My intuition is to convert frames to time via:

```
start_time = frame_start / fps
end_time = frame_end / fps
```

the convert time to sample position with:

```
start_sample = int(math.floor(start_time * sr))
end_sample = int(math.floor(end_time * sr))
```

Is this correct? Or is there something I'm missing? I'm worried that there will be loss of information since I'm converting the samples into ints with floor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say you have

```
fs = 44100                # audio sampling frequency
vfr = 24                  # video frame rate
frame_start  = 10         # index of first frame
frame_end  = 10           # index of last frame
audio = np.arange(44100)  # audio in form of ndarray
```

you can calculate at which points in time you want to slice the audio

```
time_start = frame_start / vfr
time_end = frame_end / vfr         # or (frame_end + 1) / vfr for inclusive cut
```

and then to which samples those points in time correspond:

```
sample_start_idx = int(time_start * fs)
sample_end_idx = int(time_end * fs)
```

Its up to you if you want to be super-precise and take into account the fact that audio corresponding to a given frame should rather be starting half a frame before a frame and end half a frame after.
In such a case use:

```
time_start = np.clip((frame_start - 0.5) / vfr, 0, np.inf)
time_end = (frame_end + 0.5) / vfr
```

Comment: What if I just wanted to sample an instance (one index's worth) of audio? Can I still start half a frame before the input index?

Comment: Not sure what you are asking for. You want to cut audio that corresponds to just one frame? - sure, but it will be very short audio clip and probably you won't hear a thing except maybe a short "burp"

Comment: Yep! That's exactly what I'm expecting :) I just wanted to make sure that the audio-visual correspondence was kept

Answer (score 1):

Your solution is just fine. Assuming your sample rate is 16000, the flooring will cause a video/audio desynch on the order of 4.166e-05 seconds, which is orders of magnitude below what human ears are able to discern.

```
import math

fps = 60
frame_start = 121
frame_end = 181

sr=16000

start_time = frame_start / fps
end_time = frame_end / fps

start_sample = int(math.floor(start_time * sr))
end_sample = int(math.floor(end_time * sr))

print(end_time-end_sample/sr) # 4.166666666671759e-05
```